# Ubuntu 20.04.01 keeps dropping internet connection

Tags: wireless, internet

I installed ubunutu on our old laptop about 6 months ago which has breathed new life into. it All has been fine until this last week.

The wifi connection keeps on dropping - it will last for about 4-5 mins after switching on the laptop and then suddenly the internet speed goes slow and then it just disconnects. If i switch it to airplane mode and then back on again, it connects again instantly and is ok for another few mins, but then drops again.

I have my main router and then a couple of access points and it behaves the same with all of them. I've ordered a ethernet cable to see how it works with a wired connection but that wont turn up for a couple of days.

Anything i can try or test to help diagnose what the issue could be?

Cheers, Mike

Comment: I have this exact same issue, however mine lasts longer in between disconnects. You're not alone!

Comment: its weird - i've been connected for 10-15 mins now with no issue. Its seems to have a mind of its own!

Comment: I noticed the same thing- it's very on and off and will mostly happen at the most inconvenient times possible. I thought it was my router or something but I switched provider and router... no fix :(

Comment: @mjs19780 I have no solution for you, but it would probably help if you provide info about your hardware and network settings.

Comment: Look at the logs. `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`

Comment: Check results for `iwconfig` after a disconnect and see if power management is on

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but finally looking at this again - i have been using a wired connection this morning, which seems to stay connected for a while, then runs into connection issues.
I grabbed the network manager logs -

you can see i plugged in the wired connection at 9:29 -

Nov 10 09:29:58 mike-Ideapad-Z575 NetworkManager[619]: <info>  [1605000598.1037] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp1s0) as default for IPv>

Then 15 mins later its starts getting in a twist. I'll paste below as the comment box is not big enough

Comment: <info>  [1605001517.5624] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
<info>  [1605001517.5676] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
info>  [1605001517.5683] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
<info>  [1605001517.5687] policy: set 'TALKTALK3D24B2' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 ro>
<info>  [1605001517.8639] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
<info>  [1605001517.8695] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp1s0) as default for IPv>

Comment: <warn>  [1605001661.5407] sup-iface[0x565102d15200,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (r>
<info>  [1605001661.5473] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> di>
<info>  [1605001661.6463] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected ->>
<info>  [1605001662.7661] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> aut>
<info>  [1605001662.7751] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating >
<info>  [1605001662.7782] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> >

Comment: <info>  [1605001662.7932] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake>

Comment: After this, i find that switch the wifi off and then plug the wired cable back in, internet comes back.
I'll monitor it to see if drops again with wifi off now in case that is confusing it somehow